# How to get list of azure container images which are affected after security scans?

Tags: linux, azure, security, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I know how to get repositories, we can use
`az acr repository list --name myregistry`.

But, how to get repositories with tags that are having security/vulnerability issues after security scans using azure cli?

Comment: could you please mention which commandlet you have tried to get this and what error you got!

Comment: @HariKrishna I have tried to get list of repositories using the mentioned command in post. I haven't faced any error. I was looking for how to find the repositories with tags which have security/vulnerability issues?

Answer (score 1):

***There is no way to get repositories with tags that are having security/vulnerability issues after security scans using Azure CLI***.

You can get the scan results (security vulnerabilities, recommendations) of the scanned resource using ***Azure Portal***, ***Azure Resource Grap***h and ***REST API*** as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-container-registries-introduction#can-i-get-the-scan-results-via-rest-api).

If you have the assessment Ids, then you can get the scan results using combination of REST API and Az CLI Cmdlets:

**REST API**:
[image]

**Azure CLI**:

```
az rest --method get --url GET {api to get security vuls} --url-parameters
```

[image]